# Can I use a Dutch debit card in UK public transport?

Tags: uk, tickets, public-transport, payment-cards

I have a Dutch ING vpay debit card with a chip and NFC.
Can I use it at UK bus/tube terminals?

Comment: I don't think the UK has a unified country-wide system for buses. Can you narrow it down to a bus company or region?

Comment: The international fee on the debit card may well be more expensive than the journey itself. You can get credit cards specifically for the purpose of using abroad that don't charge fees as long as you pay them off in full each month. I have a Mastercard that I can use anywhere around the world that just uses Mastercard's exchange rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [TFL](https://tfl.gov.uk/fares/how-to-pay-and-where-to-buy-tickets-and-oyster/pay-as-you-go/contactless-and-mobile-pay-as-you-go).

> Visa and V PAY (some cards issued outside the UK aren't accepted)

V PAY cards are accepted but your mileage may vary widely depending on the card

Answer (score 1):

I have used my ING Meastro card successfully in the London underground system, friends have used their Vpay card, mine did not work but that might be that it was a card so new it had not yet been used in the Netherlands yet. My new ING Vpay card has not yet been used in the Underground.

But not all cards from all banks are reported to work so keep an alternative handy if you have that.